# Application Name for the connections to WebSphere MQ on z/OS

Tags: java, jboss, jms, ibm-mq, zos

Using WebSphere MQ on z/OS for messaging and the WebSphere MQ resource adapter within JBoss EAP 6, I want to set the **Application Name** that appears when viewing the active handles on a queue.

The default is **WebSphere MQ Client for Java** and I have not managed to change it. I have no administrative access to the queue / queue manager, I am just the sender posting messages to it.

My configuration for the queues / queue manager are located in the JBoss EAP config file at the resource adapter configurations. I have tried - without success - setting the application name using a config-property inside the connection definition, for example:

```
<config-property name="PutApplName">
    my application name
</config-property>
```

I have also tried names like applicationName, applName, appName, application or JMS_IBM_MQMD_PutApplName. The latter and the name from the example I have taken from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/msg/client/jms/JmsConstants.html) and [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm25450_.htm).

How can I change the displayed application name?
Is this even possible without using the specific WebSphere MQ classes inside the java application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.dev.doc%2Fq030790_.htm
Somewhere buried in there, it says its not supported for z/OS.

> Note: Queue managers running on z/OS® platforms do not support setting
>   application names.

Comment: Well, this is awkward, but now i know it isn't possible. Thank you very much!